# Import products in Magento from a different database

Tags: mysql, database, magento, import

I'm a newbie here so I would like to apologize in advance if the question was already been answered.

My problem is: I have a simple table for storing products. The table is something like this:

```
id -> product ID
product_name -> name of the product
product_price -> price of the product
```

and so on..

My database is MySql.

I need to import this table inside a Magento installation in order to display the products correctly within Magento. How can I do that? Which Magento tables do I need to work on?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using magmi.

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page

Using magmi, you would be able to take your simple table as a csv, add a few more columns, and then feed the csv into magmi.